# Condition specification using angular through WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have a scheduling appointment/booking app project I'm a little stuck on.

I'm using asp.net MVC, entity for database, hooking it up through webAPI and managing it with angularJS.

It's basically a booking engine to book appointments:

My DB is one table that holds id, firstname, lastname, phone, orderdate, ordertime, and isBooked bool with entity.

I have a basic get/post action going on in my apicontroller,
I get and post it with angular.

My html side looks like this:

Date:

```
    <div class="selectContainer" ng-show="orderdate">
        <label for="time">
            Hours Available:
        </label>

        <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="hour in hours">

            <input type="checkbox" id="{{ hour }}-{{ $index }}"  data-ng-model="ordertime" ng-disabled="ordertime">

            <label for="{{ hour }}-{{ $index }}">
                {{ hour }}<br>
                <span ng-if="ordertime" data-ng-model="ordertime">Booked</span>
                <span ng-if="!ordertime">Available</span>
            </label>

        </div>
        <label data-ng-model="ordertime">selected hour is : {{hour}}</label>
    </div>

</div>
```

But I can't seem to add ordertime to database from the date selected inside the jquery pickadate snippet.

Also I cant seem to add the bool for isBooked boolean entity class...

Any ideas on how to approach this?
Heres a plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/HZBe7vl8Ea7fEQpKNzsC?p=preview

Webapi controller

`public class CustomerController : ApiController
    {
        BookingDbContext db = new BookingDbContext();`

```
    // GET api/customer
    [ActionName("get"), HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Customer> Emps()
    {
        return db.Customers.ToList();
    }

    // GET api/customers/5
    public Customer Get(int id)
    {
        return db.Customers.Find(id);
    }

    // POST api/customers
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(Customer model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Customers.Add(model);
            db.SaveChanges();

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, model);
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }
    }

    // PUT api/customer/5
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(Customer model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(model).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;    
            db.SaveChanges();

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, model);
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }
    }

    // DELETE api/customer/5
    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
    {
        Customer emp = db.Customers.Find(id);
        if (emp == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        db.Customers.Remove(emp);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, emp);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your controller code and the entire HTML form?

Comment: yeah heres a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/HZBe7vl8Ea7fEQpKNzsC?p=preview

Comment: Also your WebApi Controller code? What do you mean you don't seem to be able to? Is your controller being called?

Comment: Edited post to include the api code, every thibg works correctly it posts all the inputs except the ordertime and isbooked bool value. I assume that i have to add the $scope.hours array inside $scope.ordertime. somehow, is there a way to do it, like $scope.ordertime = function() {$scope.hour = ordertime}?